# NServiceBus Worker checking in with capacity of 0

Tags: msmq, nservicebus

I am using NServiceBus 3.3.  I am trying to get a new Pre-Prod-Environment setup.

It all works fine in production and in one of my existing Pre-Prod-Environments with my existing configurations.

But in my new Environment, I am getting my workers checking-in with a capacity of 0.  (They check-in with a capacity of 1 in the working Environments).

**Again, the configs are the same between the Environments.** (Except for machine names of course.)

**Any idea why this could happen?**

This is the output of my log (with Queue names and machine names changed):

```
2015-05-07 10:53:33,904 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Host [(null)]  - Going to activate profile: NServiceBus.Distributor, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2015-05-07 10:53:33,904 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Host [(null)]  - Going to activate profile: NServiceBus.Production, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2015-05-07 10:53:33,919 [1] INFO  NServiceBus.Host [(null)]  - Going to activate profile: NServiceBus.PerformanceCounters, NServiceBus.Host, Version=3.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9fc386479f8a226c
2015-05-07 10:53:33,935 [1] WARN  Distributor.myFromQueue [(null)]  - No transport configuration found so the distributor will default to one thread, for production scenarios you would want to adjust this setting
2015-05-07 10:53:33,950 [1] INFO  Distributor.myFromQueue [(null)]  - Endpoint configured to host the distributor, applicative input queue re routed to myFromQueue.worker@DistributorHost
2015-05-07 11:10:05,015 [Worker.13] INFO  Distributor.myFromQueue [(null)]  - Worker myFromQueue@WorkerMachine has started up, clearing previous reported capacity
2015-05-07 11:10:05,030 [Worker.13] INFO  Distributor.myFromQueue [(null)]  - Worker myFromQueue@WorkerMachine checked in with available capacity: 0
```

And this is the relevant part of my worker config file:

```
  <MsmqTransportConfig NumberOfWorkerThreads="4" MaxRetries="5" />
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
  <MasterNodeConfig Node="DistributorHost" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="Bus.MyMessageAssembly" Endpoint="QueueForTheDistributor@DistributorHost" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and was able to resolve it by deleting the queues (myfromqueue and myfromqueue.retries) on the worker agent.  NServiceBus automatically recreated the queues and everything started processing again for me.